# Dom to Image with CSS

Tags: leaflet, html2canvas, headless-browser

I am trying to convert the following output to image in javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/dharanbro/hp8bg8qs/

I tried with the following packages

1. `dom-to-image`
2. `html2canvas`

`dom-to-image` works with chrome but not with IE. Also with `htm2canvas` I have tried writing all css properties as inline CSS and neither it works.

Also I can use any headless browser package at server to do the same. What is the possible way to convert the rendered dom to image with IE support

Answer (score 0):

Try [Chrome Headless Screenshots](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) functionality.

Comment: `chrome --headless --screenshot https://www.chromestatus.com/` opens the  browser always. how to use it?